# Is there a way to iterate over a list, but remove/add elements to/from the list during the iteration, but still iterate over the the whole list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, recursion, foreach

An example:

```
for item in exampleList:
   exampleMethod(item) #method will add items to the exampleList
   exampleList.remove(item)
```

This foreach loop will need to iterate through the entire exampleList, whilst items are being added and removed from the exampleList.
By the entire exampleList I mean the elements that are added aswell.

I thought one possible way could be by recursion,  however, could be a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Not with this way. Use `while exampleList` instead

Comment: like this `for item in exampleList[:]:`

Comment: @VishalSingh this worked perfectly thank you

Comment: @VishalSingh can you explain this magic please? Is the complexity actually `o(n^2)` or am I missing something?

Comment: @Gulzar `exampleList[:]` iterates over the copy of the original list so when you make changes to the original list it does not have any effect on the copy made earlier. take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207427/7865368

Comment: @VishalSingh in the answer you linked, the top rated comment: "Note to anyone reading this, this is VERY slow for lists. remove() has to go over the WHOLE list for every iteration, so it will take forever". I think this is worth noting.